# count values in a list using RDDs in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am stuck in a problem of finding the count of each salary for each city, I am using just RDDs to solve the problem, that means no DF used and no functions from any library.

my code is `data= cities.map(lambda x: ((x.split()[0], int(x.split()[1])))).groupByKey().mapValues(list)`

the output of this code is `('cityX',[54,40,43,54,43,55])`

I want to find the count of each salary for cityX and then take the maximum count for this city.

I am using PySpark python shell.

desired output is `('cityX',[(54,1),(40,1),(43,1),(54,1),(43,1),(55,1)])`

what operation can I use to give each salary number 1 and then count the 1's for each one, by keeping the key as it is?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to add a 1 to each RDD element as a new tuple `(RDDElement, 1)` and `groupByKey` and `mapValues(len)` to count each city/salary pair. For example:

```
salaries = sc.parallelize([("city1",100000),("city2", 85000),("city1",155000),("city2",180000),("city2",180000)])

salaries.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).groupByKey().mapValues(len).collect()
```

Results in:

```
[(('city2', 85000), 1),
 (('city2', 180000), 2),
 (('city1', 100000), 1),
 (('city1', 155000), 1)]
```

Comment: thanks, I have used this way using 
map(lambda x: ((x.split()[0], int(x.split()[1])),1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x+y) 
But, finally I want for each city the most frequent salary, and if there is two salaries appeared the same number of times, then it will take the min salary.
using this way I couldn't find it. So, I thought of making list for each city.

if there is any way to continue in your way or mine, please let me know?

Comment: You can use reduceByKey to compare the counts from the results in my answer. The reduce function would take the greater of the counts and it would look something like `lambda x,y: x if x > y else y`.